# how do you merge two data frames without the duplicate fields in R

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge to data set by a common column called Date.

these are my 2 data frames:

```
> head(cpu)
       Metric_Name                Date MAXVAL
38821 HostCPUUsage 2019-01-03 14:00:00     21
38822 HostCPUUsage 2019-01-03 15:00:00     23
38823 HostCPUUsage 2019-01-03 16:00:00     22
38824 HostCPUUsage 2019-01-03 17:00:00     19
38825 HostCPUUsage 2019-01-03 18:00:00     16
38826 HostCPUUsage 2019-01-03 19:00:00     15
> head(work)
      Metric_Name1                Date  Val
34506 Transactions 2019-01-03 14:00:00 2754
34507 Transactions 2019-01-03 15:00:00 2594
34508 Transactions 2019-01-03 16:00:00 2252
34509 Transactions 2019-01-03 17:00:00 3363
34510 Transactions 2019-01-03 18:00:00 1368
34511 Transactions 2019-01-03 19:00:00 1282
```

when I do this:

merge(cpu, work, by=c("Date")

I get multiple Date fields . I need unique Date field for Work and cpu:

```
> head(ddd)
                 Date Metric_Name1  Val  Metric_Name MAXVAL
1 2019-01-03 14:00:00 Transactions 2754 HostCPUUsage     21
2 2019-01-03 14:00:00 Transactions 2754 HostCPUUsage     18
3 2019-01-03 14:00:00 Transactions 1994 HostCPUUsage     21
4 2019-01-03 14:00:00 Transactions 1994 HostCPUUsage     18
5 2019-01-03 15:00:00 Transactions 3316 HostCPUUsage     22
6 2019-01-03 15:00:00 Transactions 3316 HostCPUUsage     23
```

It should be like this:

```
> head(ddd)
                 Date Metric_Name1  Val  Metric_Name MAXVAL
1 2019-01-03 14:00:00 Transactions 2754 HostCPUUsage     21
6 2019-01-03 15:00:00 Transactions 3316 HostCPUUsage     23
```

Comment: `merge(cpu, work, by="Date", all=FALSE)`

Comment: nope, did not work, I get duplicate Date entries for the same date.

Comment: Don't see why it would be any different but could try `dplyr::inner_join()`?

Comment: inner_join() also gives me the duplicate date fields

Comment: Are you sure you have unique "Dates" in the cpu data.frame?

Answer (score 0):

the `inner_join` function from the `dplyr`package should be what you are looking for:

you can use it as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(cpu, work, by = "Date")
```

The output you provided resulting from using `merge` are not comprehensible since  a value of 1994 does not occur in the data you provided.